Failed Catching Error Record Not Found with GORM
I tried to select a record with the code below.
err := tx.Clauses(clause.Locking{Strength: "UPDATE"}).Where("description = ?", item.Description).First(&exist).Error
            if errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
                err = r.db.Create(&entity.Item{
                    Name:        item.Name,
                    Description: item.Description,
                    Quantity:    item.Quantity,
                    OrderID:     order.ID,
                }).Error
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }
            }

But, the program stops and doesn't execute the create function. How can I handle the error?
I expect the error to be caught by err and then the program executes inserting new data to database.
The log:
record not found
[5.093ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM "items" WHERE description = 'iPhone' ORDER BY "items"."id" LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE

